# ODBC Driver Manager error

Tags: odbc

I have this project on visual basic which I am running on Virtual machine on windows xp. i am getting following error.

> Run-time error'-2147467259(80004005)': [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager]Data Source name not found and no default driver specified

how to make connect it to odbc and make it run on virtual machine??

Comment: install Odbc driver in your system.

Answer (score 0):

1. change the target location to "%windir%\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe" in properties of Data Sources (ODBC) in Control Panel\Administrative tools.
2. Open ODBC Data Source -- open System DSN tab -- click on add--Click Microsoft access Driver(.mdb,.accdb) --- click finish
3. Give it Data Source Name - dsname , Click on Select button---located your database file. Then clicked ok and again ok.

Make appropriate changes in your vb project with the data source name with "dsname" .
Now try running your application